# Node.js Mysql stopped querying after a few minutes

Tags: mysql, node.js, discord.js

I have a Discord.js bot with a MySQL as a database. The problem I'm having is that the SQL stopped querying after a random amount of times, **the only way that I could fix this is by restarting the node.js app**

My bot involves a lot of sql querying inside of an sql query similar to :

```
sql.query(`SELECT xxxxx` , (err, res) => {
   sql.query(`SELECT xxxxx`, (err, result) => {}
}
```

And my SQL pool code is :

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
const pool = mysql.createPool({
    host    : "localhost",
    port    : 3306,
    user    : "x",
    password: "x",
    database: 'x'
});

let sql = {};
sql.query = function(query, params, callback) {
  pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
    if(err) { 
      if (callback) callback(err, null, null); 
      return; 
    }
    
    connection.query(query, params, function(error, results, fields) {
      connection.release();
      if(error) { 
        if (callback) callback(error, null, null); 
        return; 
      }
      if (callback) callback(false, results, fields);
    });
  });
};

module.exports = sql;
```

My VPS is running fine, my SQL server is running fine as well. I'm not sure what's causing the problem.

***My current solution is running a cronjob every 30 minutes to restart the application, I'm not sure if this is a good practice or not.***

Comment: When you said "random amount of times", does that mean sometimes it stopped after 2 minutes, sometimes after 5 minutes etc. like that?

Comment: "My current solution is running a cronjob every 30 minutes to restart the application, I'm not sure if this is a good practice or not." Absolutely not, needing to manually start an application because it crashes every 30 minutes?? What makes you think that is a good idea??

Comment: check that your connections are being properly released back to the pool

Comment: @tcadidot0 Yes, it can range from 2-15 minutes.

Comment: @YunfeiChen Ah, that's good to know. What are the consequences of constantly restarting it? And no, it doesn't crash, the application and commands works just fine, only those with SQL queries won't work.

Comment: @Prism if you were doing a bank transaction, would you like the bank to say, they need to restart their severs?? And it takes 5minutes?? Its an accessbility problem, and also you are making the CPU sitting idle wasting resources while you are restarting...

Comment: @YunfeiChen Ah that's a bit ironic since I'm creating a verification bot, won't be fun if someone had to wait 5 minutes just to join a server. Thanks for the heads up, I'll have to figure out what's wrong with my SQL handler.

Comment: Just to be clear, how do you know the query stopped? Does it provide any error message?

Comment: @tcadidot0 No errors, it just stopped the whole command by itself. It seems like it's trying to connect but on a timeout until I reset the whole application/bot.